# Parse XML as CSV

Tags: xml, csv

I am looking for a method to grab XML files and parse them as CSV. The XML files will have the same optional data elements but I will basically be grabbing those XML files every X minutes parse only certain elements out and output to a CSV for further processing such as importing into SQL, etc. I have used XSLT and XMLDOM for parsing XML, however, that was for HTML output. I am open to using ASP, VBScript, batch scripting, JavaScripting, etc. Most scripting language (IIS) or can possibly use C# of necessary although am new to C# and not really yet handling complex apps as of yet.

Any thoughts on languages and methods to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT isn't restricted to producing HTML; you can produce any output with it.

Since you have already workded with it, it sounds like your best option.